# Verify state of boolean variables in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, boolean

I'm using some flags to keep track of actions like:

```
is_registered = True
has_paid = False    
has_phone  = True

if (is_registered and has_phone and has_paid):
    do_something
```

But if the number of fields increase I prefer to store it in a dictionary

```
user_flags = {'is_registered':True,'has_paid':False,'has_phone':True}

if (user_flags['is_registered'] and user_flags['has_paid'] and user_flags['has_phone']):
    do_something
```

And again that might be ok for a small number of items but if I've gets say over 50 items it gets quite verbose

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `and` a bunch of boolean variables stored in a dict?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
>>> user_flags = {'is_registered':True, 'has_paid':False, 'has_phone':True}
>>> all(user_flags.values())
False

>>> user_flags = {'is_registered':True, 'has_paid':True, 'has_phone':True, 'one_more_flag':True}
>>> all(user_flags.values())
True
```

---

Or, to inverse the logic with [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
>>> user_flags = {'is_registered':True, 'has_paid':False, 'has_phone':True}
>>> not any(not value for value in user_flags.values())
False

>>> user_flags = {'is_registered':True, 'has_paid':True, 'has_phone':True, 'one_more_flag':True}
>>> not any(not value for value in user_flags.values())
True
```

Comment: The genexp is unnecessary; `all(user_flags.values())` would do the same thing.

Comment: @user2357112 my bad. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of information you want to keep visible at the `if` line.
One "full visibility" option could be,

```
def check_flags(user, flags):
    return all([user[flag] for flag in flags])

user_flags = {'is_registered':True,'has_paid':False,'has_phone':True}

if check_flags(user_flags, ['is_registered', 'has_paid', 'has_phone']):
    do_something()
```

while if you don't mind possibly having to go search back for the flags you're checking, just embed the flags in a function and do `if user_is_ready():` and you're done.